# Switching letters on C++ challenge

Tags: c++, string

[Challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/c-tutorial-strings): Given 2 strings of input, output three lines:

1. The character count in each string, separated by a space;
2. The strings concatenated together;
3. The strings together, separated by a space, and the first letter of both words swapped.

Code I produced:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   // Complete the program
  string firstString, secondString;
    cin>>firstString>>secondString;
    cout<<firstString.length()<<" "<<secondString.length()<<"\n";
    cout<<firstString<<secondString<<"\n";
    string wierdString;
    wierdString = secondString[0];
    for ( int i = 1; i <= firstString.length(); i++ ) {
        wierdString += firstString[i];
    }
    wierdString = wierdString + " " + firstString[0];
    for ( int j = 1; j <= secondString.length(); j++ ) {
        wierdString += secondString[j];
    }
    cout << wierdString;
    return 0;
}
```

Test case:

> **Input (stdin)**
>      `abcd ef`
>   **Your Output (stdout)**
>       `4 2`
>       `abcdef`
>       `ebcd af`
>   **Expected Output**
>       `4 2`
>       `abcdef`
>       `ebcd af`
>   **Compiler Message**
>   *Wrong Answer*

---

To me (being a beginner), the output looks just like the output expected. Is there an issue with my code (other than the `using namespace std;`) that would cause this to not work? I'm still a beginner, and I'd like to learn what is wrong.

Comment: you are probably outputting some more (invisible) characters somewhere. Check newlines etc.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling I did try by copying the output expected and the output received into Notepad++, and turned on all hidden characters. They seemed to match (CR/LF at the end of each line).

Comment: Why all of that looping code just to swap values?  There is `std::swap` that does that for you.  `std::swap(firstString[0], secondString[0]);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because, as a beginner, I did not know about that. I'm attempting to do the challenges in order, and using the information made available to each challenge.

Comment: But as a beginner, you should learn how to research such things.  Also `weirdString = secondString[0] + firstString.substr(1) + " " + firstString[0] + secondString.substr(1);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Absolutely! But I also like trying things first on my own ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string `s` is indexed from 0 to `s.length() - 1` (inclusive). You are iterating with the following condition: `i <= firstString.length()` that means reading from behind the end of your string.

Comment: That was the issue! Thanks!

Comment: Lesson learned: Don't trust Notepad++ :) Try something like 'od' or 'xxd' to dump file content. For win, I only know of xvi32.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to be working fine and you are getting the desired output as well. I think nothing can go wrong with it
[image]

Comment: You had an extra space in the second output. I didn't. The issue was solved by remembering that the `.length` property was 0-indexed